# Passing lots of props to react children

Tags: reactjs

Let's say I'm passing many props to a child component. Currently I'm doing:

```
function ParentComp(){
  const [state1, setState1] = useState();
  const [state2, setState2] = useState();

  function someFunction(){
    // code
  }

  const data = dataReturningFunction(state2);

  return(
    <ChildComp
      state1={state1}
      setState1={setState1}
      state2={state2}
      setState2={setState2}
      someFunction={someFunction}
      data={data}
      // etc... 
    />
  )
}

function ChildComp(props){
  // access everything with props.state1 etc...
}
```

I'm using the data / code / functions in other children and the parent, so can't just demote it all to the child.

The issue is when this gets to be 10+ properties I'm passing down... lots of repeating myself.

I'm sure there's something straightforward and obvious, but I'm learning, and haven't been able to find an easier way.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) an object like:

```
function ParentComp(){
  const [state1, setState1] = useState();
  const [state2, setState2] = useState();

  function someFunction(){
    // code
  }

  const data = dataReturningFunction(state2);

  const childProps = { 
     state1, 
     setState1,
     state2, 
     setState2,
     someFunction,
     data
  };

  return(
    <ChildComp {...childProps} />
  )
}
```

Comment: Does the spread prevent me from having to in the child write: `props.childProps.state1` etc? I'm still learning its usefulness

Comment: No actually, you can use the passed props just like `props.state1`, `props.state2` and so on

Comment: You'll then use `props.state1` in the child.

Answer (score 5):

Just pass an object as a single prop object with all the attributes you need

```
return(
    <ChildComp
      propsObj=
        {
          state1,
          setState1,
          sate2
          // and so on 
        }
    />
  )
```

And then you can deconstruct props object directly in the child component argument like this

```
function ChildComponent ({state1,setState1,state2}){
    // ...
}
```

This way you do not have to enter `props` prefix when referencing the properties

Answer (score 2):

Two ways you can use to pass props to child components

1.

```
return(
  <ChildComp
    {...this} 
  />
)
```

`{...this}` will send whole current class component to child component and it will receive all varialbles, states, props and methods

2. You can use Context API to pass props to child components, but functions we cannot send with this

First option is preferred

Comment: Wouldn't that assume I'm using the class constructor? I'm using functional components.

Comment: Yes this will work in case of class components, for functional components we can create variable and pass that

const compProp = { 
     state1, 
     state2, 
     setState2,
     handleFunc,
     dataVar
  };